# duplicates in bigquery table spread seconds of each other

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my BigQuery table called [games] (around 5 million rows) where I have rows with the following structure:

```
user_id    game_id   game_play_time
1234567    3444432   2017-05-30 15:26:57 UTC
1234567    3444432   2017-05-30 15:26:58 UTC
1234567    3444432   2017-05-30 15:26:59 UTC
9876544    8586588   2017-05-30 23:26:11 UTC
4638889    8698798   2017-05-30 15:26:58 UTC
4638889    8698798   2017-05-30 15:27:58 UTC
```

I need to remove rows which have the same user_id and game_id BUT where the time difference between following games 'is equal or less' than a second (keeping the first occurrence).

The result should look as follow:

```
user_id    game_id   game_play_time
1234567    3444432   2017-05-30 15:26:57 UTC
9876544    8586588   2017-05-30 23:26:11 UTC
4638889    8698798   2017-05-30 15:26:58 UTC
4638889    8698798   2017-05-30 15:27:58 UTC
```

Comment: based on input data in your question  - please show expected output!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Just added the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  user_id,
  game_id,
  MIN(game_play_time) AS game_play_time
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    game_id,
    game_play_time,
    SUM(step) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, game_id ORDER BY game_play_time) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id,
      game_id,
      game_play_time,
      CASE WHEN IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(game_play_time, LAG(game_play_time) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, game_id ORDER BY game_play_time), SECOND), 0) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS step
    FROM YourTable
  )
)
GROUP BY user_id, game_id, grp
--  ORDER BY user_id, game_id, grp
```

You can test it with below dummy data (from example in your question + few more rows to make it more generic)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS(
  SELECT '1234567' AS user_id, '3444432' AS game_id, TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 12:26:57') game_play_time UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567', '3444432', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 12:26:57') UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567', '3444432', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 13:26:57') UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567', '3444432', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 13:26:57') UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567', '3444432', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 15:26:57') UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567', '3444432', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 15:26:57') UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567', '3444432', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 15:26:58') UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234567', '3444432', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 15:26:59') UNION ALL
  SELECT '9876544', '8586588', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 23:26:11') UNION ALL
  SELECT '4638889', '8698798', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 15:26:58') UNION ALL
  SELECT '4638889', '8698798', TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 15:27:58')
)
SELECT 
  user_id,
  game_id,
  MIN(game_play_time) AS game_play_time
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    game_id,
    game_play_time,
    SUM(step) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, game_id ORDER BY game_play_time) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id,
      game_id,
      game_play_time,
      CASE WHEN IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(game_play_time, LAG(game_play_time) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, game_id ORDER BY game_play_time), SECOND), 0) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS step
    FROM YourTable
  )
)
GROUP BY user_id, game_id, grp
-- ORDER BY user_id, game_id, grp
```

Comment: @BrunoGG - did you have chance to try?

Comment: Thank you :) sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work for you?

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  game_id,
  MIN(game_play_time) game_play_time
FROM(
  SELECT
    user_id,
    game_id,
    game_play_time,
    lead_time,
    (UNIX_SECONDS(lead_time) - UNIX_SECONDS(game_play_time) <= 1) diff
FROM(
  SELECT 
    user_id,
    game_id,
    game_play_time game_play_time,
    LEAD(game_play_time,1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, game_id order by game_play_time) lead_time
FROM data
)
)
GROUP BY user_id,game_id, diff
ORDER BY user_id, game_id, game_play_time
```

where data is your input data, I defined it like so:

```
WITH data AS(
select '1234567' as user_id, '3444432' as game_id, timestamp('2017-05-30 15:26:57') game_play_time union all
select '1234567' as user_id, '3444432' as game_id, timestamp('2017-05-30 15:26:58') game_play_time union all
select '1234567' as user_id, '3444432' as game_id, timestamp('2017-05-30 15:26:59') game_play_time union all
select '9876544' as user_id, '8586588' as game_id, timestamp('2017-05-30 23:26:11') game_play_time union all
select '4638889' as user_id, '8698798' as game_id, timestamp('2017-05-30 15:26:58') game_play_time union all
select '4638889' as user_id, '8698798' as game_id, timestamp('2017-05-30 15:27:58') game_play_time
)
```

Even though it seems to be working here I'm not sure if still there's some corner case where it won't work. Maybe the results in your data might show if everything is ok.

Comment: Thank you! The problem if you use `MIN(game_play_time)` is that you will only keep the first occurrence even if they are separated by more than a second (rows that we want to keep) -- by removing it and only keeping `game_play_time` and then adding it in the GROUP BY seems to do the trick. I need to do more verifications.

Comment: Hi, can you maybe give an example of the output you want? I thought you'd want to keep only the first ocurrence but maybe you have some other rule in mind for sequential rows.